# Invalid memory address using gorutine (golang)

Tags: go, xml-parsing, request, buffer, goroutine

I am working with a code that works only if I make it run as a blocking routine... but if I use `go executeTheFunction` I always get `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. To summarize the code a little would be something like that.

```
func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
    app = c; //this is a "global" variable to be used in callBackFunction 
    options = "foo";
    client  = NewClient()
    client.RequestAsynch(options, callBackFunction);
}
func callBackFunction(message string){
    reader := bytes.NewBufferString(message)
    _, err := xmlpath.Parse( reader )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    flusher, ok := airshopping.Response.Out.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
      panic("expected http.ResponseWriter to be an http.Flusher")
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(airshopping.Response.Out, "whatever")
    flusher.Flush()
}

func (client * Client)RequestAsynch(message Message, callback func(string)) {
    Response := client.Request(message)

    message_aux := ""
    reader := bufio.NewReader(Response.Body)
    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err==nil {
            message_aux = message_aux + string(line)
            if strings.Contains(message_aux, "<!-- AG-EOM -->"){
                go callback(message_aux)
                message_aux = ""
            }
        }else{fmt.Println("ERROR", err);break;}
    }
}
```

Ok... I am going to explain a little. The `RequestAsynch` is in a different package and what it launchs a request to other server. This other server reponse with multiple xml... the body of these xml looks like:

```
<!-- Header status:ok -->
<all_the_xml_response>
<!-- AG-EOM -->
```

So... when the line by line loop detect this `"<!-- AG-EOM -->"` is that one of the xml is completely received, and the callBack functions should be executed (with a gorutine). The mission of this callBack function is parse the xml and, after a process of parsing, send some data back to the javascript in the client side.

The error I am always getting is this:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x4f8c09]

goroutine 80 [running]:
bufio.(*Writer).Write(0xc042454540, 0xc0422d4000, 0x11076, 0x12000, 0xc04202fb30, 0x4683b7, 0x11076)
    C:/Go/src/bufio/bufio.go:598 +0x149
net/http.(*response).write(0xc04234d0a0, 0x11076, 0xc0422d4000, 0x11076, 0x12000, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0422d4000, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1525 +0x157
net/http.(*response).Write(0xc04234d0a0, 0xc0422d4000, 0x11076, 0x12000, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc042824000)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1495 +0x6b
fmt.Fprintf(0xb65e80, 0xc04234d0a0, 0xc042824000, 0x11076, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0421445f0, 0xb, 0xc0422f5e00)
    C:/Go/src/fmt/print.go:182 +0xb0
ndc-console-test/app/controllers/ndcmethods.GetOffers_AS(0xc042594000, 0xef7f)
    F:/Proyectos_Trabajo/work/src/ndc-console-    test/app/controllers/ndcmethods/airshopping.go:98 +0x7a1
created by github.com/open-ndc/ndc-go-sdk.(*Client).RequestAsynch
    F:/Proyectos_Trabajo/work/src/github.com/open-ndc/ndc-go-sdk/ndc_client.go:143 +0x25c
2017/05/17 16:42:56 reverseproxy.go:316: http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:55058: connectex:A connection can not be established because the target computer expressly denied the connection.
```

And after this error... I need to restart the server, because it doesn´t allow make a new connection.

One of the things I saw, is that if I remove this line `_, err := xmlpath.Parse( reader )` in the callBackFunction it works fine. And of course if I change this line: `go callback(message_aux)` for `callback(message_aux)` (without the goroutine) it works fine too and it has no problem to parse the xml.

Does anyone know a solution about how to avoid this error using goroutines??

Thank you very much.

### EDIT

I think I did not express myself well with how the other server responds, this is how looks the (multiple) responses:

```
<!-- Header status:ok -->
<the_xml_response_of_one_response_or_one_chunk>
<!-- AG-EOM -->
<!-- Header status:ok -->
<other_xml_response>
<!-- AG-EOM -->
<!-- Header status:ok -->
<other_more_xml_response>
<!-- AG-EOM -->
```

Comment: An http.ResponseWriter is only valid during the life of the request. There's no reason for an async callback pattern like this in Go.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, it appears the problem is that the HTTP response is being written out as soon as the parent function returns, by the time the new goroutine gets a chance to try, the writer is no longer usable.

This is part of the design of `net/http`, so I suspect your `RequestAsynch` can't be written as it was intended. Why does it need to be asynchronous? Each request is already handled in its own goroutine.

BTW, `strings.NewReader` is probably more appropriate than `bytes.NewBufferString`, since you don't need the full buffer interface.

Comment: Hi @nothingmuch. Thanks for your answer. Let me explain a little better. The thing is that I don´t make multiple request... I only make one request and the other server sends me many xml responses (please, look at what I have edited in the body of the question about how the server responses), in this way I need the callback function to be called once for each xml. If I use `callback(message_aux)` instead `go callback(message_aux)` it works.

Comment: It doesn't change anything as far as I can tell, in both cases you'll need to wait at the end of `RequestAsynch`, and wait until all the goroutines you started have finished. You can do this by using a `sync.WaitGroup`, or by having them send their results over a channel instead of using the response writer directly, but the fact remains that you cannot use the response writer after the HTTP handler returns

Comment: Hi again @nothingmuch. And... why does it work if I remove this line: ` _, err := xmlpath.Parse( reader )` in the callBackFunction?? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because then the goro is executed quickly enough to write h the output before it's flushed to the client. This is a kind of race condition.